# How can I use SqlDataSource properly with parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, sqldatasource

Here is my code I'm using (with oracle developer tools):

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="FirstNameSQL" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UserQueries %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UserQueries.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT &quot;FIRSTNAME&quot; FROM &quot;USERS&quot; WHERE (&quot;USERNAME&quot; = '%?')">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="UsernameLabel" Name="firstname" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

What I'm trying to do is to make a query with a parameter from a label's text. But it doesn't return anything. 
Maybe my data retrieving method is wrong, which is here:

```
DataView dv4 = (DataView)FirstNameSQL.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    foreach (DataRow r in dv4.Table.Rows)
    {
        FirstNameLabel.Text = (string)r[0];
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using `SqlDataSource`? You should be using `OracleCommand` if you just want to fetch data from an Oracle Database into a DataView.

Comment: Your question has partially inspired me to write a [blog post](https://masonmcg.com/blog/entry/release-of-fancystoredemo-and-sharpnoty).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `SqlDataSource` to programatically retrieve data, you should use the `OracleCommand` class. `SqlDataSource` should only be used if you're binding directly to a `GridView` or some other control. Really, `SqlDataSource` shouldn't be used at all, because data access shouldn't happen in the UI layer in a properly designed system.

Using the [official Oracle NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/).

```
public static DataTable GetDataTable(OracleCommand command)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (var connection = GetDefaultOracleConnection())
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();
        dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
    }
    return dt;
}

public static OracleConnection GetDefaultOracleConnection()
{
    return new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString); //just get a connection string from somewhere
}

//usage
var command = new OracleCommand("select firstname from users where username=:username");
command.Parameters.Add("username", UsernameLabel.Text.Trim());
command.BindByName = true; //incredibly important if more than one parameter
var dt = GetDataTable(command);
DataView dv = dt.AsDataView();

//now get the results. I prefer getting it from the DataTable instead of DataView. Easier to use Linq
if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    /* Below line requires extra reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions */
    FirstNameLabel.Text = dt.AsEnumerable().First().Select(r => r.Field<string>("firstname"));
}
else
{
    FirstNameLabel.Text = "not found";
}
```

---

The above should have shown you how you can get data from the database programatically. But it's still not following a good architecture, because we've used database access code in our code behind. Our code behind should have no idea about the database implementation details. So let's start from scratch and architect this a little better. First, we should define a class that contains the user details. I'm going to call it `ApplicationUser` so we don't conflict with the `Page.User` property.

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    public string Username {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

That's cool, now we've defined what we need for our ApplicationUser. But we also need a way to load users from the database. That should not happen on our code behind or in our model, but it should happen in a data layer.

```
public class MySiteOracleRepository
{
    private string ConnectionString {get; set;}

    public MySiteOracleRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public ApplicationUser GetUserByUsername(string username)
    {
        OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("select firstname, lastname, username from users where username=:username");
        DataTable dt = OracleDatabaseHelper.GetDataTable(command, ConnectionString);
        ApplicationUser user = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => new ApplicationUser(){
            FirstName = r.Field<string>("firstname"),
            LastName = r.Field<string>("lastname"),
            Username = r.Field<string>("username")
        }).Single();
        return user;
    }
}
```

That's good. Now we need to implement `OracleDatabaseHelper.GetDataTable()` which will perform the actual access to our database.

```
public class OracleDatabaseHelper
{
    public static DataTable GetDataTable(OracleCommand command, string connectionString)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Now, what does that give us? An easy and reusable way to get information about users. Since we have this code, we don't need to repeat ourselves everytime we need to retrieve user information, thus following the DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle. So let's see what our page's code behind can look like now.

```
private MySiteOracleRepository repo {get; set;}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    repo = new MySiteOracleRepository(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);

    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadUserInfo();
    }
}

protected void LoadUserInfo()
{
    ApplicationUser user = repo.GetUserByUsername(UsernameLabel.Text);
    FirstNameLabel.Text = user.FirstName;
    LastNameLabel.Text = user.LastName;
}
```

See how simple our page has become? And notice it'd be pretty easy to write a new `MySiteMySqlRepository`, `MySitePostgresRepository`, `MySiteMongoRepository` etc, and you only would need to really make a new class. You would have to modify your page to use the different repository types, but that problem can be solved with [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). But I won't go into that here, because I probably through enough new stuff at you as it is.

Comment: I added the NuGet package, but already in the beginning the OracleCommand class is not recognized as it says: the type or namespace could not be found

Btw, thanks for the great explanation

Comment: @kisbovan93 Anytime you get an error like that, it means you need to add a using statement to bring the namespace in scope. If you're using Visual Studio it can do it automatically. Right click the code with an error and go to Resolve and choose an option there. If you're not using VS, then I believe you need to add `using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;`

Comment: There is no such option as Resolve and when I'm trying to add the reference manually, it doesnt accept it.

Comment: @kisbovan93 What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: It is visual studio 2013 ultimate

Comment: @kisbovan93 Do you see the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` assembly in your References folder of your project?

Comment: @kisbovan93 Your question inspired me to make a demo application, see the source [here](https://github.com/mason-mcglothlin/FancyStoreDemo/tree/master/src). Of particular interest to you, the `FancyStoreDemo.DataRepositories.Oracle` project.